# Accessing Description and Acceptance criteria in AzureDevops User Stories from PowerBI via oData API

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I am trying to retrieve the Description and Acceptance Criteria fields from the user story work item type from Azure DevOps from PowerBI.

I have tried the oData feed, and also configuring an analytics view, and scoured the online documentation all to no avail.

Has anyone managed to ever do this successfully?  (What I actually want to do is establish the existence and/or the length of both fields).

Comment: Hi, were you able to get the Acceptance Criteria and Description details in PBI. I am new to PBI nd working on similar implementation. Can you guide me on the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Description and Acceptance Criteria fields are not available via the oData feed.

If you want to see what is available check out the entity model at this url.

`https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{OrganizationName}/{ProjectName}/_odata/v3.0-preview/$metadata`

What you can do is supplement the OData feed in PowerBI with calls to the Azure DevOps Rest API, to get the Description and Acceptance Criteria fields. You can do that via PowerBI functions.

Have a look at these two articles by [Colin Dembovsky](https://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/azure-devops-build-and-test-reports-using-odata-and-rest-in-powerbi) and [Wouter de Kort](https://wouterdekort.com/2019/09/12/measuring-your-way-around-azure-devops/) to get an idea of what's possible. They include some good examples of supplementing the feed data with Rest calls.

Edited with an example to get you started:

Your custom function can look like this

```
let
    Source = (project as text, workItemId as text) =>
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://dev.azure.com/{ORG-NAME}/" & project & "/_apis/wit/workitems/" & workItemId & "?api-version=5.1"))
in
    Source
```

Then your Query using the OData feed and calling the function

```
let
    Source = OData.Feed("https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{ORG-NAME}/{PROJECTNAME}/_odata/v3.0-preview", null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    WorkItems_table = Source{[Name="WorkItems",Signature="table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(WorkItems_table,{{"WorkItemId", type text}}),
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Description", each GetWorkItemAdditionalData([ProjectName], [WorkItemId])),
    #"Expanded Description" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Invoked Custom Function", "Description", {"fields"}, {"Description.fields"}),
    #"Expanded Description.fields" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Description", "Description.fields", {"System.Description", "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria"}, {"Description.fields.System.Description", "Description.fields.Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria"})
in
    #"Expanded Description.fields"
```

Comment: The first link leading to Colin Dembovsky blog is broken, the correct link is https://colinsalmcorner.com/azure-devops-build-and-test-reports-using-odata-and-rest-in-powerbi/

Comment: Unfortunately this is only partly working for me: When making the request I got "Error" in each single field in the new column description. While using the Diagnostics I was able to get the following insights: 
Response:
HTTP/1.1 203 Non-Authoritative Information
Content-Length: 15704

Authorization is not possible in the GET request as it requires to be Anonymus authorization before which is impossible to get connection to the OData.Feed

Comment: Solved the issue by combining this answer and this guide: https://wisedatadecisions.com/2021/05/03/parameterize-an-api-request-in-power-query/

Comment: Hi, I am new to PBI and working on getting Acceptance Criteria and Description into PBI as these are not available in Analytics View. Can you help in a sample PBIX with a similar implementation or some step-by-step guide please?