# How to get Work Item Description through Azure Devops Services REST API

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to get all Azure Devops Work Items with their description using this endpoint ?
[https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{Organization}/_odata/v3.0-preview/](https://analytics.dev.azure.com/%7BOrganization%7D/_odata/v3.0-preview/)

I tried to look in WorkItems table but could not find the description field

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these methods: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)

Example:

[image]

To use with odata check this topic: [Accessing Description and Acceptance criteria in AzureDevops User Stories from PowerBI via oData API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023313/accessing-description-and-acceptance-criteria-in-azuredevops-user-stories-from-p)

Comment: Awesome thank you